# In Deadpool 2, would this happen if that didn't happen?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

So in Deadpool 2 we see that Cable

> travels back in time to save his family by killing Firefist, who kills his wife and daughter in the future.

To do so, he

> enters the Icebox by force and fails because of Deadpool recovering his powers.

That made me think:

> Deadpool was going to die in the Icebox, without his regeneration powers due to his multiple cancers. Cable's action leads to saving Deadpool's life, and forces to move the inmates in the Icebox to another high security prison, and Firefist uses that moment to escape.

So the question is:

> If Cable didn't travel back in time, would Firefist be able to escape prison, kill the director and ultimately, kill Cable's family?

Comment: This seems way too opinion based, there is no way to know what *would* happen; people can only guess as to what *could* happen.

Comment: Don't think too hard on time travel, it'll make your head hurt. Might as well ask if Deadpool ever gets himself into the situation the plot demands given that he went back in time and undid a major factor in his Act I motivation.

Answer (score 13):

After Wade left the Icebox, Firefist befriended Juggernaut, on Wade's advice to "make friends with the biggest guy in here". Since that advice was given before Cable's attack, that occurs in an untouched timeline - presumably, Wade and Firefist had the same conversation resulting from the cafeteria fight in any timeline where Wade dies of cancer in prison. In that case, Firefist would have befriended Juggernaut after Wade died of cancer.

When Firefist is on the prisoner transport that's transporting the inmates of the Icebox to another facility, he manages to get some sort of panel on the wall open, and he manipulates the wiring inside to get his cell door open. At that point, Juggernaut takes his signal to break out of the transport.

Obviously we don't see any glimpse of a Cable-free timeline, but there's two things we know:

- Firefist took Wade's advice to heart, and considered Juggernaut his ticket out of prison.
- Firefist is technologically adept enough to crack open one of the DMC's electronic locks and unlock it.

Based on this, I think we can assume that in a timeline where Cable does not arrive and Wade dies, Firefist would manage to get a lock open at the Icebox which would let Juggernaut free, and the two would escape together.